# How to find velocity as a function of distance/time when force is given as a function of distance?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, time, velocity, distance

Let's say force between two particles is given as F=k/r² where 'r' is distance between two particles and k is a constant. I am having trouble in finding velocity as a function of distance between particles. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assume that a small moving mass is attracted toward (or repelled from) a large stationary  mass, then you can integrate the force over the distance from the starting to end points to get the work done.  This will be equal to the change in the kinetic energy of the moving mass.  If you want to let both masses move relative to the center of mass, the principle is the same, but the calculations get more complicated.